# How to deal with user uploaded images

Tags: ubuntu, images, storage, upload, processing

I'm using Restlet as backend trying to create a small web app.

I am allowing users to upload their profile images, but not sure where to store them. Google tells me to store it in the file system and store the image path in DB which make sense.

So should I store them in a public web folder in which the web front end lives? But wouldn't that allow people to access all the profile images very easily?

If i don't store the images in the public web directory, where should I store them and how do I protect them?

My server is Ubuntu server 12.04
thanks in advance

BTW any advice on how should I process the images upon upload? I'm trying to convert all formats to png and resize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check every image, if you use PHP, you can call getimagesize()
2. You can save images inside www, but, you can disable directory indexing, or,
3. Save images outside www, then, you need to read the images internally by like reading file.
4. It's better also to disable PHP on the directory where the images stored.
5. I would also prefer to check the image when loading it using getimagesize(), I am sure if you use image libraries, you can detect invalid image types in case when malicious code injected.

Comment: Restlet is for Java, nothing mentioned PHP... #2 sounds a good option, if the filenames are generated randomly.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Well Restlet is a Java web API framework but php examples does provide some insights. I think I'll just store the images inside www folder and disable folder browsing, generate a random image name for each id and store it in DB